# SQL datediff with negative parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I am a complete noob to SQL and trying to understand why this query returns "115":

```
select datediff(yy, -3, getdate())
```

Comment: @LasseEdsvik question is `why this query returns "115":`

Comment: DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate ) , You need to pass proper date to get the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`datediff` takes three Parameter. The first is the `interval`, the second the `start date` and the third the `end date`. You are passing -3 as start date, there we can show:

```
SELECT CAST(-3 AS datetime) -- results in '1899-12-29 00:00:00.000'
```

And because 2014 - 1899 is 115, you will get this as result.

Comment: @haim770, yes that is because he selects the `year` and not the `day`. If you enter `-366` the you have the result `116`

Answer (score 1):

Because DATEDIFF() calculates an interval between 2 dates, and you specified year -3 in one of them.

Firstly, the date "zero" is 12/30/1899 on SQL server.
Secondly, your "-3" was an incorrect date format and it thus replaced it with its 0

2014 - 1899 = 115

Use DATEADD() instead to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: `-3` is converter into `-3` days before the `date zero` which is `1900-01-01 00:00:00`. `-3` passed as integer is a correct date Format. Integer values can always be used as valid date.

Comment: thanks! gave you the answer for explaining that date "zero" is 1899

Comment: @blizz, the definition `zero` given in this answer is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

DateDiff gives difference in years/date/months etc based on what you have given in first parameter. second and third parameter are datetime values which will be used to calculate the difference i.e. (param2 datetime value - param3 datetime value).

Now in your case param2 is "-3"
run this queries in you ms sql and observe the outputs :

```
select CAST(-3 as datetime)
select GETDATE()
select datediff(yy, -3, getdate())
```